# A list with no duplicates or an ordered set

Tags: haskell

Is there a library which provides a data structure, which preserves the order of items and does not contain any duplicates? And does there exist a proper name for such a data structure?

I expect it to behave like a list with `nub` applied after each operation on it. Of course I don't expect it to be implemented as ineffectively.

Comment: It reminds me of Java's [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). So I suppose a similar approach could be used for an immutable functional data structure.

Comment: If your type belongs to `Ord`, you could use a `Data.Set` to write and `ordNub` that takes `O(n*log m)`, where `n` is the number of items, and `m` the number of unique items. If `Hashable` and not `Ord`, you could do the same with `Data.HashSet`. Would that be sufficiently un-inefficient?

Comment: Hello 2013, did you arrive at a solution?

Comment: @ABot I'd recommend an abstraction over a combination of a list and an ordered or a hashed set.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one solution:

Use a [fingertree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree) with the `Set` monoid as your measure. Then on inserts, check membership first, using the `measure` of your full fingertree. This gives you `O(log(n))` cons and snoc, `O(1)` deletes.

Here's another solution:

Pair a normal list with a normal `Set` and get basically the same effect. You get better constant factors, but `O(log(n))` deletes.

Here's a question: What do you want to happen on insert of a duplicate? Should the existing position be preserved? The new position? Priority Queues may be close to what you want, depending.

Answer (score 0):

[`OSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ordered-containers/docs/Data-Set-Ordered.html#t:OSet) from `ordered-containers` seems to do what you want.