# Set-Like data structure that maintains insertion Order?

Tags: haskell, data-structures

#### The properties I'm looking for are

- initially maintains insertion order
- transversing in the insertion order
- and of course maintain that each element is unique

#### But there are cases where It's okay to disregard insertion order, such as...

- retrieving a difference between two different sets
- performing a union the two sets eliminating any duplicates

[Java's LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) seems to be exactly what I'm after, except for the fact it's not written in Haskell.

#### current & initial solution

The easiest (and a relevantly  inefficient) solution is to implement it as a list and transform it into a set when I need too, but I believe there is likely a better way.

#### other ideas

My first idea was to implement it as a `Data.Set` of a `newtype` of `(Int, a)` where it would be ordered by the first tuple index, and the second index (`a`) being the actual value. I quickly realised this wasn't going to work because as the set would allow for duplicates of the type `a`, which would have defeated the whole purpose of using a set.

#### simultaneously maintaining a list and a set? (nope)

Another Idea I had was have an abstract data type that would maintain both a list and set representation of the data, which doesn't sound to efficient either.

#### recap

Are there any descent implementations of such a data structure in Haskell? I've seen [Data.List.Ordered](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.6.1/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html) but it seems to just add set operations to lists, which sounds terribly inefficient as well (but likely what I'll settle with if I can't find a solution). Another solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524533/a-list-with-no-duplicates-or-an-ordered-set), was to implement it via [finger tree](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.pdf), but I would prefer to not reimplement it if it's already a solved problem.

Comment: Would a [stack](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Abstract_data_type#Stack) suit your purpose?

Comment: Probably not, uniqueness of the elements is key, and a stack makes no such guarantee. Unless of course I manually check for uniqueness, which is not ideal

Comment: I also think you should use a monoidally-annotated tree, as suggested in the finger tree solution (you can do this with other trees too, e.g. my splaytree package).  For non-fingertree trees, the monoid could be `(Max Int,Set val)`, which will let you maintain insertion order (via the `Max Int`) and reduce duplicates (via `Set val`).  Then you'll have O(log n) inserts and lookups, and O(n) traversals. (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/splaytree doesn't implement this in particular, but it shows the technique for Maps)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly use `Data.Set` with what is isomorphic to `(Int, a)`, but wrapped in a newtype with different a `Eq` instance:

```
newtype Entry a = Entry { unEntry :: (Int, a) } deriving (Show)

instance Eq a => Eq (Entry a) where
    (Entry (_, a)) == (Entry (_, b)) = a == b

instance Ord a => Ord (Entry a) where
    compare (Entry (_, a)) (Entry (_, b)) = compare a b
```

But this won't quite solve all your problems if you want automatic incrementing of your index, so you could make a wrapper around `(Set (Entry a), Int)`:

```
newtype IndexedSet a = IndexedSet (Set (Entry a), Int) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

But this does mean that you'll have to re-implement `Data.Set` to respect this relationship:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.Set (Set)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (sortBy)

-- declarations from above...

null :: IndexedSet a -> Bool
null (IndexedSet (set, _)) = S.null set

-- | If you re-index on deletions then size will just be the associated index
size :: IndexedSet a -> Int
size (IndexedSet (set, _)) = S.size set

-- Remember that (0, a) == (n, a) for all n
member :: Ord a => a -> IndexedSet a -> Bool
member a (IndexedSet (set, _)) = S.member (Entry (0, a)) set

empty :: IndexedSet a
empty = IndexedSet (S.empty, 0)

-- | This function is critical, you have to make sure to increment the index
--   Might also want to consider making it strict in the i field for performance
insert :: Ord a => a -> IndexedSet a -> IndexedSet a
insert a (IndexedSet (set, i)) = IndexedSet (S.insert (Entry (i, a)) set, i + 1)

-- | Simply remove the `Entry` wrapper, sort by the indices, then strip those off
toList :: IndexedSet a -> [a]
toList (IndexedSet (set, _))
    = map snd
    $ sortBy (comparing fst)
    $ map unEntry
    $ S.toList set
```

But this is fairly trivial in most cases and you can add functionality as you need it.  The only thing you'll need to really worry about is what to do in deletions.  Do you re-index everything or are you just concerned about order?  If you're just concerned about order, then it's simple (and `size` can be left sub-optimal by having to actually calculate the size of the underlying `Set`), but if you re-index then you can get your size in `O(1)` time.  These sorts of decisions should be decided based on what problem you're trying to solve.

---

> I would prefer to not reimplement it if it's already a solved problem.

This approach is definitely a re-implementation.  But it isn't complicated in most of the cases, could be pretty easily turned into a nice little library to upload to Hackage, and retains a lot of the benefits of sets without much bookkeeping.

Comment: Oh okay I see what you're doing, this is a much better solution. I was reading it like "Wouldn't having Equality disconnected with Ordering cause operations like insertion, and member, have `O(N)` complexitity?", but then noticed you were also ordering by the element as opposed to the index.

Comment: @ABot It's always a good idea to have your `Eq` and `Ord` instances very closely related, which is what I chose to do in this case.  The index is really only used on insertion and when converting back to a list so that everything comes out in the same order you put it in, but other than that it's essentially just meaningless metadata.

Comment: I usually avoid `newtype`-ing pairs, preferring regular `data` types with a constructor taking two arguments, since it usually leads to the same runtime representation and performance, while reducing the number of parentheses in the code. Is there any special reason to prefer a `newtype` here?

Comment: @chi the same reason you don't like to, personal preference.  I would accept seeing this with a new data type just fine, but I do believe there would be a slightly larger overhead, depending on the optimizations performed. I know with newtypes and tuples ghc has special optimization rules.

Comment: @chi I would also say that going with `newtype`s helps to show that the solution exists with types that are isomorphic to tuples, just with different behaviors.  Since this is precisely the purpose of `newtype`s, I figured it would be a better choice than using a `data` type.

Comment: One downside to this approach is that, in order to traverse by insertion order, it's necessary to go via list (or otherwise sort the data by Index), which will add complexity relative to using a (List,Set) pair.  But maybe it's more important to have efficient deletions.

Comment: @yairchu I'm not sure, that would be left up to the original asker.  An easy solution would be something like `union a b = fromList (toList a <> toList b)`